# how to make stacked ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

want to make stacked ggplot for timeseries

```
 >air2
 dayofmonth total dept
1           1  1107  380
2           2   918   92
3           3  1089  113
4           4  1086  235
5           5  1063  218
6           6  1084  325
7           7  1129  180
8           8  1133  166
9           9   918   72
10         10  1088  214
11         11  1114  180
12         12  1047  195
13         13  1110  421
14         14  1165  216
15         15  1174  228
16         16  1010  115
```

I tried this but didnt get the expected graph:

```
mdata <- melt(air2,id=c("dayofmonth"))

ggplot(mdata, aes(x=Time,y=value,group=variable,fill=variable)) +
  geom_area(position="fill")
```

Comment: Well, if you look at `?geom_area`, the default value of `position` is `"stack"`, but you override that by setting `position = "fill"`.

Comment: Your dataset and provided ggplot code do not tell from which (factor) variable you would like to create stacked bars.